# How to add files to git without adding the sub directory

Tags: git, github

using the following command to add a file on github

$ git add foldername/filename

the command adds the file plus the sub directory on github, but i just want to add the file without the sub directory. I know that i can simply move the file into the git directory add then use the command $git add filename but i would like to keep the file in the folder.

Comment: This is a pretty bizarre way to use Git.  If you did this, then `git status` on the local machine would always complain that the file had been deleted (from the root directory) and that there was an untracked subdirectory (`foldername`), and you'd have to use a special command every time you tried to commit a change to this file on the local machine.  Could you explain why you're trying to do this, and maybe someone can provide a more helpful answer.

Comment: This really, really seems you are trying to use git in extremely wrong way. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: currently when i push my app to a git repository, it results in repo_name/folder/file.. what i want is to push just the files to the repo so that it results in repo_name/files without the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to keep the file inside `foldername` locally. At the same time you expect it to be in the root of git repo.

In such case you just need to have git repo to be initialized inside that folder.

If you start from scratch (not git repos) the you should be able to achieve that using such commands:

```
cd foldername
git init
git remote add origin URL_TO_YOUR_GITHUB_REPO
git add filename
git commit -m 'COMMIT_MESSAGE'
git push --set-upstream origin master
```